# How can I have Glimpse instrument all requests, but still restrict access to the Glimpse panel?

Tags: glimpse

I'd like Glimpse to instrument all requests to my site, but still restrict the Glimpse.axd page and the HUD to selected people.

I already have a custom runtime policy, but when this policy restricts access to the Glimpse HUD, it also doesn't instrument the request.

Is what I'm asking possible? I have a hunch it has something to do with [Runtime Event](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/RuntimeEvent.cs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your policy is either returning `RuntimePolicy.Off` or `RuntimePolicy.On`.

What you should do instead is not turn Glimpse off, but return `RuntimePolicy.PersistResults` so that Glimpse will capture the information about the request, but not inject HUD or the full client.

You can see more about [the various levels of Glimpse policies on GitHub](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Extensibility/RuntimePolicy.cs).